# Backbone.js change event not firing after set() call similar to a succesful one

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am changing my MyModel's `longitude` and `latitude` attributes in two cases, but my MyView only notices one of them:

- When FAKE_LOCATION == true, I set (lat,long) in `update` and **no change event is fired**.
- When FAKE_LOCATION == false, I set (lat, long) in the callback of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`: `success` and **change event is fired**.

---

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,'success','update');
        this.update();
    },

    update: function() {
        if(!FAKE_LOCATION){
            if(navigator.geolocation)
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success);
        }else{
            this.set({
                latitude : 37,
                longitude : -122
                                    //previously, I was using constants here
            });
        }
    },

    success: function(position) {
        this.set({
            latitude : position.coords.latitude,
            longitude : position.coords.longitude
        });
    }
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.render);
    }
});

var myModel = new MyModel();
var myView = new MyView({ model : myModel });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `FAKE_LOCATION_LAT` and `FAKE_LOCATION_LONG` are constants, then you set `latitude` and `longitude` during initialization in the `.initialize()` method. Subsequent calls to `.set()` won't actually change the value, so no change takes place, and no `change` events are triggered.

Add this to your code to make sure the values actually change:

```
}else{
    this.set({
        latitude : 37 + Math.random(),
        longitude : -122
    });
}
```

Comment: I see. Nevertheless, I need to be able to change `latitude` and `longitude` after `initialize()` and preferably, have *an event* fired.

Comment: The problem is you're **not** _changing_ `latitude` and `longitude` after `initialize()`. You're just setting them to the same values over and over again.

Comment: I don't understand. The constant values and the ones acquired from `navigator.geolocation` are different, based on my personal location at this moment.

Comment: When FAKE_LOCATION == true you never use "the ones acquired from `navigator.geolocation`."

Comment: That is correct. But it doesn't change the fact that `.set()` is called and I need a change event, just like when the change event does fire when I `.set()` with the `navigator.geolocation` return.

Comment: So you're expecting Backbone to trigger a change event when nothing has changed. It doesn't do that. You can, of course, override the set method and make it do whatever you want.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstandings from my part before, Stephen. Thank you for your patience. By said logic, shouldn't it fire in case of the edited code above?

Comment: No. Your edit has no effect. But I really don't know how to be any clearer. Maybe this is a silly question (if so, forgive me), but you do understand what the English work "change" means, don't you? (I ask because your profile lists your location as Belgium.)

Comment: Thank you for a constructive edit to your answer. I understand why that could work in contrast with my different solutions, although unfortunately, it doesn't.